# Why can't I edit the tags of some mp3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3, tagging

I am having this weird problem while trying to edit the tags of my music library: I modify them with EasyTAG and there seems to be no problem (VLC recognizes the changes I make), but I then transfer the music to my audio player and it does not recognizes the changes. Note, that this issue does not happen all of my records, but only a small portion (less than 1%). What could be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's good to put one of mp3 files here.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar How can I do that? Don't see an option to add files.

Comment: You may upload it in an uploading file website and put it's URL here.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar Thanks for your interest, but I think I have found the problem. It seems that my problem is being caused by an APE tag in the MP3 file. I already asked a question about that if you are interesred.